# Error starting vreplication engine: error in connecting to mysql db with connection <nil> Vitess on kubernetes

Tags: vitess, kubernetes-vitess

kubernetes version: v1.16.3

linux version: 7.3.1611

Starting Vitess cluster on kubernetes using default operator.yaml and 101_initial_cluster.yaml, one of example-vttablet-zone1-xxx pod is restarting forever.
using `kubectl logs -f example-vttablet-zone1-2548885007-46a852d0 -c vttablet` to see the logs, i got

```
W0706 07:42:02.200507       1 tm_init.go:531] Cannot get current mysql port, will keep retrying every 1s: net.Dial(/vt/socket/mysql.sock) to local server failed: dial unix /vt/socket/mysql.sock: connect: no such file or directory (errno 2002) (sqlstate HY000)

E0706 07:42:02.285406       1 engine.go:213] Error starting vreplication engine: error in connecting to mysql db with connection <nil>, err net.Dial(/vt/socket/mysql.sock) to local server failed: dial unix /vt/socket/mysql.sock: connect: no such file or directory (errno 2002) (sqlstate HY000), will keep retrying.
E0706 07:42:02.285504       1 state_manager.go:276] Error transitioning to the desired state: MASTER, Serving, will keep retrying: net.Dial(/vt/socket/mysql.sock) to local server failed: dial unix /vt/socket/mysql.sock: connect: no such file or directory (errno 2002) (sqlstate HY000)
I0706 07:42:02.285527       1 state_manager.go:661] State: exiting lameduck
E0706 07:42:02.285539       1 tm_state.go:258] Cannot start query service: net.Dial(/vt/socket/mysql.sock) to local server failed: dial unix /vt/socket/mysql.sock: connect: no such file or directory (errno 2002) (sqlstate HY000)
I0706 07:42:02.285553       1 tm_state.go:305] Publishing state: alias:<cell:"zone1" uid:2548885007 > hostname:"10.233.107.217" port_map:<key:"grpc" value:15999 > port_map:<key:"vt" value:15000 > keyspace:"commerce" shard:"-" key_range:<> type:MASTER db_name_override:"vt_commerce" mysql_hostname:"10.233.107.217" master_term_start_time:<seconds:1625527268 nanoseconds:196807555 >
```

I didn't change any yaml in operator directory, anyone know why is this?

Comment: resolve it by set replicas to 3 in 101_initial_cluster.yaml